# Cannot allocate memory in multiprocessing python

Tags: python-3.x, memory, multiprocessing

I want to apply my function (f1) to array of numbers (cdr_test) using multiprocessing. My code:

```
cdr_test = [x for x in range(0, 100000)]

def f1(el):
    a = Counter() #make new vector for each cdr
    for k,v in d3.items():
        if el in v:
            a = a + Counter(itertools.product([el], v))  
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(20)
    results = pool.map(f1, cdr_test)

    pool.close()
    pool.join() 

    out = open('out.txt', 'w')
    for result in results:
        for k,v in result.items():
            out.write('\t'.join(map(str,k))+"\t"+str(v)+"\n")
    out.close()  
    pool.close()
```

I have 'cannot allocate memory'. If I use an array of smaller length (100), then everything works.

Stacktrace:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b8dc4a3d12b3> in <module>()
     9 
     10 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 11     pool = mp.Pool(1000)
     12     results = pool.map(f1, cdr_test)
     13     #new section

    /home/fedorovaad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/context.py in   Pool(self, processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
116         from .pool import Pool
117         return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
--> 118                     context=self.get_context())
    119 
    120     def RawValue(self, typecode_or_type, *args):

/home/fedorovaad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py in      __init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild, context)
    166         self._processes = processes
    167         self._pool = []
--> 168         self._repopulate_pool()
    169 
    170         self._worker_handler = threading.Thread(

/home/fedorovaad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py in  _repopulate_pool(self)
    231             w.name = w.name.replace('Process', 'PoolWorker')
    232             w.daemon = True
--> 233             w.start()
    234             util.debug('added worker')
    235 

/home/fedorovaad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py in start(self)
    103                'daemonic processes are not allowed to have  children'
    104         _cleanup()
--> 105         self._popen = self._Popen(self)
    106         self._sentinel = self._popen.sentinel
    107         _children.add(self)

/home/fedorovaad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/context.py in _Popen(process_obj)
    265         def _Popen(process_obj):
    266             from .popen_fork import Popen
--> 267             return Popen(process_obj)
    268 
    269     class SpawnProcess(process.BaseProcess):

/home/fedorovaad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py in __init__(self, process_obj)
     18         sys.stderr.flush()
     19         self.returncode = None
---> 20         self._launch(process_obj)
     21 
     22     def duplicate_for_child(self, fd):

/home/fedorovaad/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py in _launch(self, process_obj)
     65         code = 1
     66         parent_r, child_w = os.pipe()
---> 67         self.pid = os.fork()
     68         if self.pid == 0:
     69             try:

OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

Are there ways to solve this?

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Thanks, I added.

Answer (score 2):

The code you show is different from the one in the error.

```
---> 11     pool = mp.Pool(1000)
```

You are trying to spawn way too many processes, the OS will run out of memory before it can allocate them all.

You don't need this many processes to carry on your job, just use `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` to know how many CPUs your platform has and spawn a pool of that size.